# Does the Magic Circle ritual block teleportation?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

The Magic Circle ritual says:

> An affected creature whose level is lower than your Arcana check result minus 10 cannot pass through the circle, affect creatures through the circle’s boundary, or affect the boundary in any way.

The definition of teleportation is:

> Teleportation takes no time. The target disappears and immediately appears in the destination that the teleporting creature chooses. **The movement is unhindered by intervening creatures, objects, or terrain.** (emphasis mine)

Also, generally, teleportation is considered dimensional travel, so it's not passing *through* the magic circle so much as bypassing it by moving through another dimension.

So from what I see, you couldn't use Magic Circle to keep someone from teleporting through it. Right?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the idea that teleportation is *considered dimensional travel* from? I only ask because I can find no such description in either the *PHB* or *RC*.

Comment: I guess I was pulling it from the description of Fey Step, which reads "You step through the boundary between the planes, disappearing for a moment before reappearing somewhere else."

Comment: Not sure where you're now pulling that description from (the Eladrin racial power from the PHB has a different description) but that's not important. *Fluff*, which is the *italicised* description near the top of a power, doesn't have any mechanical bearing in 4e (unless the DM decides otherwise). Teleportation can, and is, *described* in many different ways in terms of *fluff*.

Answer (score 2):

Teleportation is movement, as shown in your second quoted blurb.  Teleportation is not blocked by certain things that block normal movement, but power effects may still block it.  Magic Circle is an effect that blocks movement for some creatures.  Magic circle does not specify any particular vulnerabilities regarding teleportation.  Magic circle thus blocks teleportation for some creatures in some circumstances.

Note, though, that teleportation effects do not 'move through' the intervening space between start and end points.  A circle of magic circle effects would not prevent a creature from reaching the unwarded center, though the creature might be barred from entering any of the various circles.

Also note that in earlier editions Magic Circle also blocks interdimensional travel.